# django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to build a Blog application. Ran makemigrations and migrate and also created superuser. But I am getting below error while running the server.

django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'blog.templatetags.blog_tags': cannot import name 'POST' from 'blog.models'

Please help me....
My models.py file is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')


from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(('draft','Draft'),('published','Published')) 
    title=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=264,unique_for_date='publish') 
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='blog_posts',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    body=models.TextField()
    publish=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft') 
    objects=CustomManager()
    tags=TaggableManager()  
    class Meta:
        ordering=('-publish',) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):  
        return reverse('post_detail',args=[self.publish.year,self.publish.strftime('%m'),self.publish.strftime('%d'),self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email=models.EmailField()
    body=models.TextField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)      
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)         
    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Commented by {} on {}'.form(self.name,self.post)
```

Comment: please give the ful traceback

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have

```
from blog.models import POST
```

in `blog/templatetags/blog_tags.py`.

Capitalisation matters in Python variable names. It should be:

```
from blog.models import Post
```

Comment: Yes I wrote Post as my Model class name is Post. But it automatically converted to POST.

Comment: Sorry I din't check it properly. Thank you so much. Really appreciate the quick help