# Is there a way to solve this: django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified

Tags: python, django, heroku, filter, django-templates

I deployed my application successfully to Heroku only to encounter this problem. It has to do with my template tags. It works just fine in development.

I tried adding:

> 'libraries': {
> 'courses_tags': 'courses.templatetags.courses_tags',
> }

to the `TEMPLATES` dictionary in settings.py but that doesn't worked.

Here is a screenshot from my Heroku log.

[heroku log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjwyj.png)

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55834373/14457833) maybe this will help you

Comment: I have scoured stackoverflow for an answer and I have definitely seen this post. It was just just a typo on the part of the OP. In my own case, the error log doesn't even help as this problem has to do with how django works, I suppose. You know...restarting the server and shhh before using a template tag 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more extensive searching, I discovered that

> import cv2

in my courses_tag.py is the cause of my problem and I used answers in this post to solve my problem.

[link to the question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469764/how-to-use-opencv-with-heroku)